# What is the difference between $post_id and get_the_ID()?

Tags: plugin-development

What is the difference between `$post_id` and [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)?

I could not find any documentation on `$post_id`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) returns [the ID of the current post](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post-template.php#L28) by way of [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post). Get post [assumes the current post to be the `global` variable `$post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post.php#L388) unless passed parameters specifying otherwise. That means that `get_the_ID()` should return the same value as contained in `$post->ID`. Using `get_the_ID()` lets you avoid dealing with the global directly, though you are dealing with it indirectly. Using `get_the_ID()` tends to be less error-prone in theme template files.

`$post_id` is a variable name used commonly to refer the post ID, but it isn't a Core variable the way that `$post` is, though it does get defined a few times in specific contexts:

```
grep -Rn '$post_id' * |grep global
wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php:25:          global $post_id;
wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php:45:          global $post_id, $comment_status, $search, $comment_type;
wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php:141:         global $post_id, $comment_status, $comment_type;
wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php:250:         global $post_id;
wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php:691: global $wp_list_table, $post_id;
wp-includes/ms-deprecated.php:115:function clear_global_post_cache( $post_id ) {
```