# Echo recent posts each with its own respective featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to create a grid-type view for a custom home page. it will be a simple grid that will contain three columns, with several previous posts in each column. I'd like for each instance to contain:

- Linked Title linked
- featured image

The problem that I'm running in to is that the same featured image is being displayed for each post. The post titles are all correct - I can see each individual, and different, post title.

How can I get this bit of code to get the featured image for *that particular* post instead of repeating the same post over and over again? Not great with PHP so I'm fairly sure the problem is in that part, just don't know what I need to change.

I also want to add a short summary and a post link, but didn't want to do that until I got this issue solved first.

Here is what I have so far in my front-page.php file:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '99' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">'; 
    echo  '<div class="fp-featured-image"> ';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'featured-image');

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<h2 class="my-post-title"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   ( __($recent["post_title"])).'</a></h2> </div> ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `$post_id`. From [this answer by @s_ha_dum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112400/31545) (*which you should go and read*).

> `$post_id` is a variable name used commonly to refer the post ID, but it isn't a Core variable the way that `$post` is.

In the context as in your question, you would want to use `$recent["ID"]` (*which will hold the current post id in the `foreach` loop*) instead of `$post_id` which will hold the page ID of the page the query is being run on