# Get array of metakey in all posts

Tags: functions, array, post-meta

My posts contain a meta-field that holds an external id.
I'm trying to create a function with a loop that goes through all posts and puts all the meta-keys in an array and returns this array.

This is what i came up with, but it seems i'm missing something. Does anyone have a clue?

```
function gather_ids ()
{

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
    );
        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
                $temp[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'json_id');
            }
            return $temp;
        } else {
        // no posts found
        echo "no posts found to delete";
        }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is unreliable and totally overboard and really really expensive. Furthermore, as already stated by @MarkKaplun, you are not calling `the_post()` which causes the `$post` global not to be updated to the current post being looped through, so the value from `get_post_meta()` will always have the same value.

Although `$post_id` might work, it is one of those crappy variables set globally that is actually used to get the comments. It is better to use `get_the_ID()` or even `$post->ID` as you are inside the loop. For extra info, read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112400/31545)

To solve your issue, I would just create a function with a custom SQL query to fetch all unique values from a specific meta key. Here is a function I have used on another answer

```
/**    
 * Description: Getting all the values associated with a specific custom post meta key, across all posts
 * Author: Chinmoy Paul
 * Author URL: http://pwdtechnology.com
 *
 * @param string $key Post Meta Key.
 *
 * @param string $type Post Type. Default is post. You can pass custom post type here.
 *
 * @param string $status Post Status like Publish, draft, future etc. default is publish
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_unique_post_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $res = $wpdb->get_col( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value 
            FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
            AND p.post_status = '%s'
            AND p.post_type = '%s'", 
            $key, 
            $status, 
            $type 
        ) 
    );
    return $res;
}
```

You can then just use it as follow to get an array of unique meta value

```
$unique_values = get_unique_post_meta_values( 'json_id' );
?><pre><?php var_dump( $unique_values ); ?></pre><?php
```

You can also build in some cache/transient system into the function to optimize it even more

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the 3rd argument true.

like

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'json_id', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, i did try that as well, but I still cant get the array

Comment: I think the problem with time of storing when you call function add_post_meta($post_id, 'json_id', $value) then please check the type of variable is array or other

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the `$post_id` to anything. You probably need to call `the_post()` at the loop and use the `$post` global to access the id.

Comment: `$post_id` is one of those (*crappy*) unknown globals that is suppose to hold the current post ID. Check [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112400/31545)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, that answer actually says "$post_id is a variable name used commonly to refer the post ID, but it *isn't a Core variable*..."   but even if it is in the context, without declaring it as a global and "moving" to the next post I assume it will not get updated....

Comment: It does work though, but I do not use it, as I said, it is crappy and is suppose to hold the post ID